# Update a textbox from an System.Timers.Timer elapsed event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Here's the code:

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 0;
        // some code
        count++;
        logOutput.Text += Environment.NewLine + count; //here's the problem
    }
```

As the title says, I want to update the textbox every time the OnTimedEvent is fired, but i'm very new to C#, and Google just gives me complicated code.

The problem: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property."

Comment: "here's the problem" : WHAT is the problem? Don't make us guess.

Comment: @Blorgbeard oh, sorry :x
HERE is the problem:
"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"

Comment: OK, try removing `static` from `private static void OnTimedEvent`.

Comment: Why is your method static in the first place?  Where is that code?

Comment: By the way, if you want to append text to the contents of a `TextBox` then don't use the `Text` property.  Call the `AppendText` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Timers.Timer` raises its `Elapsed` event on a secondary thread.  You can't safely make any changes to the UI, e.g. set the `Text` of a `TextBox`, on any other than the UI thread.  If you assign the form itself to the `SynchronizingObject` property of the `Timer` then it will raise the event on the UI thread and you can access your control(s) safely, otherwise you must somehow delegate back to the UI thread.

That said, why not just use a `Windows.Forms.Timer`, which raises its `Tick` event on the Ui thread?

Comment: It worked, thanks! and the method was static because of some copy paste... As I said, I'm very new to C#.